# Iterate from 'a' to 'x' and create a '.dat' file for each letter

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to iterate from a to x and create files a.dat, b.dat, ...,x.dat

```
int main()
{
    char letter = 'A';

    FILE *fp;
    while (letter < 0x59) {
        printf("%c", letter);
        char *fname = "";
        fname[0] = letter;
        fname= strcat(fname, ".dat");
        const char * fnam = fname;
        fp = fopen(fnam, "ab+");
        fclose( fp );

        letter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It iterates over the letters just fine, but this one line

```
fname[0] = letter;
```

crashes the program with "segmentation fault" error. In debugger it says "can't access memory at address.."
I want to create a string out of the letter and ".dat", for that I create an empty string and make it's first character the letter I want by assigning its 0 element the value of the letter. But it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Comment: You are modifying a string literal which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: If your are using c++, use `std::string`.

Comment: you haven't actually allocated any memory for `fname`

Comment: Looks like you are working with C. A "natural" C++ answer in this case would not compile as C and would probably not be helpful for you to learn C.

Comment: BTW avoid magic number as `0x59`, use 'X' instead.

Comment: obey the warning you should get for `char *fname = ""`, or increase the warning level, or get another compiler

Answer (score 4):

Just use a char array for the filename:

```
char filename[] = "_.dat";

for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'X'; ++letter) {
    filename[0] = letter;
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "ab+");
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're taking a string literal of length 0 (`""`), then attempting to (a) assign new data to it (undefined) and (b) append to it (into unallocated space).

Instead, you want a character buffer that you can safely modify:

```
int main()
{
    char letter = 'A';
    char fname[] = "?.dat";

    FILE *fp;
    while (letter < 'Y') {
        printf("%c", letter);

        fname[0] = letter;

        fp = fopen(fname, "ab+");
        fclose( fp );

        letter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work for reasons outlined below (see comments; UB stands for *Undefined Behavior*)

```
char *fname = "";  // Assign a non-modifiable pointer to fname
fname[0] = letter; // Trying to modify data at that pointer - UB
fname= strcat(fname, ".dat"); // Trying to write data past the end of buffer - UB
```

Here is how you can fix this:

```
char fname[] = "-.dat"; // Create a writable array of chars
fname[0] = letter;      // Now this assignment is allowed
// strcat is not required, because .dat is already in place
```

Note that if you compiled this in C++, you would see an error on the first line, becausem unlike C, C++ considers string literals `const char*`. This would trap the assignment on the next line as well, and the call of `strcat` too.

Answer (score 1):

you must allocate a space before using it
when this statement is executed you try to modify a literal string, that is not allowed

```
fname[0] = letter;
```

you must do something like that

```
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 20
fname = malloc(20);
```

or using an array allocated into the stack

```
char fname[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
int main()
{
    char letter = 'A';

    FILE *fp;
    while (letter <= 'Z') {
        char fname[100] = "";
        fname[0] = letter;
        fname[1] = 0 ;
        strcat(fname, ".dat");
        fp = fopen(fname, "ab+");
        fclose( fp );    
        letter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```